# how to use cpp unit

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

Is there a good book or online site discussing the use of the CppUnit, for a beginner?

Comment: What is bugging you: CppUnit in itself - or more generally unit-testing  ?

Comment: its more unit testing itself, but I understand that CppUnit is the most populare framework

Comment: I would not say it's the most popular framework. It may have a better visibility because of its name, but I doubt it's the most advocated.

Comment: It's probably most advocated because of it's name and probably because people have heard of it but haven't used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these links help?

- http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/cppunit_cookbook.html
- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/samples/testingdebugging/article.php/c4685/
- http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3214s/tools/cppunitSol.html

Comment: Two of the three links are now 404...

Answer (score 4):

When you do start to use unit-testing, don't aim for 100% coverage - that way lies madness.

Look to cover all the major methods within the class (the low hanging fruit).

When I started unit testing (via [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/)) I went for total coverage, making methods that should of been private protected and then using wrapper classes to be able to test them. Seam functions so I could test classes that were closer to the metal.

A good book on unit testing is [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1259139195&sr=8-1-fkmr2) which despite it's name talks about green fields development too, is well written and has good examples to boot.

Update: Also don't worry too much about covering every single possibility at the start when writing the tests. You will miss some stuff. I once had a test that passed but the live code would crash in that function. Running the inputs through the test showed what was wrong and allowed me to rewrite the function so it passed all tests. The original test had held strong for about 7 or 8 months before a customer (unfortunately for me) discovered the bug.

Comment: A good book to use when looking at unit testing is John Lakos's [Large Scale C++ Design](http://www.amazon.com/Large-Scale-Software-Design-John-Lakos/dp/0201633620/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1259140273&sr=8-1), in particular the parts about levelisation, so that you can concentrate on unit testing your level 0 functions first, and then build up your test suite a level at a time.

Comment: I have to say the section on levelisation is probably the most boring section (and largest) of the book, which I have to admit is very good. It probably has something to do with it being his dissertation for his doctorate.

Answer (score 2):

Unit-testing allows testing classes **in isolation**, one method at a time.

Basically a testcase creates one instance of the class being tested and the class it depends on, invoke one method and verify the method worked as expected with **assertions**.

A great way to achieve unit-testing is [Test-Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (TDD), where the unit-tests are written before the code. While this may sounds weird at first, this allows to obtain code that is testable (and tested). If the code is written first, then it might not be testable easily.

The TDD process is as follows:

RED: write a test that fails
GREEN:  write just enough code to make it pass 
REFACTOR: cleanup the code, remove duplication

---

I'm not sure CppUnit is the most widely used. It's a portation of jUnit - the Java framework - but it's quite heavy ; there exists simplified verisons: CppUnitLite, NanoCppUnit and also Cxxtest, Boost.Test and TUT, see [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B) on Wikipedia. If you're not tied to CppUnit, there is an [article comparing them](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle).

Answer (score 1):

Test Driven Development by Example: [http://www.amazon.com/Driven-Development-Example-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321146530](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)

Comment: Another good book that I own too.

Answer (score 0):

The book I turned to for "inspiration" was Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers.  He's the author of CppUnit, and wrote this book as a way to help add unit testing to a big legacy project.  If you're just starting on a new project, it's not likely to help you much, but if you're trying to get unit tests into an old project, he has a lot of good ideas.

The real problem with trying to refactor an existing project is getting the go ahead from your management.  To them, if there's no perceived benefit (no new features, risk of changing code) they may think it's not worth the expense.  You have to work hard to sell them on the real benefits (improved quality, ease of adding new code, etc.,) and in the end they may decide it's not worth it.

I've just picked up xUnit Test Patterns by Gerard Meszaros.  It actually arrived yesterday so I've only read through the first few chapters, and can't fully recommend it one way or another yet.  But so far it has provided sound advice on the author's philosophy of automated unit testing, and that may be the sort of thing you're looking for.